# Mean squared error is enormous when using Scikit Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, mean-square-error

I have been battling this problem with my MSE while predicting with regression. I have encountered the same problem with different regression models I have tried to build.

The problem is, my MSE is humongous. 83661743.99 to be exact. My R squared is 0.91 which does not seem problematic.

I manually implemented the cost function and gradient descent while doing the coursework in Andrew Ng's Stanford ML classes and I have a reasonable cost function; but when I try to implement it with SKLearn lib the MSE is something else. I don't know what I have done wrong and I need some help checking it out.

Here is the link to the dataset I used: https://www.kaggle.com/farhanmd29/50-startups

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')

#checking the level of correlations between the predictors and response
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True)

#Splitting the predictors from the response
X = df.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = df.iloc[:,4].values


#Encoding the Categorical values
label_encoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:,3] = label_encoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,3])

#Feature Scaling
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

#splitting train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=0)

#Linear Regression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

pred = model.predict(X_test)

#Cost Function
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test,pred)
mse
```

Comment: How much is "enormous"? Please share value(s). Keep also in mind that, in contrast with classification metrics like accuracy, regression metrics like MSE do not have any natural scale, i.e. one cannot say by a simple look if they are "large" or "low" - it depends on the scale of the data to be predicted.

Comment: @desertnaut the value I had was 83661743.99. funny enough my Rsquared was 0.91

Comment: It would be good if these values were in the question instead of the comments - kindly suggest you edit & update your post to include them

Answer (score 0):

As you used standard normalization for scaling, the values of the dataset can be humongous. As desertnaut said, MSE is not scaled so it can be huge due to the big values of the dataset. You can try to normalize data using a MinMaxScaler to get the iput between [0-1]

Comment: I tried that before and I still had a large value. I also forgot to add that my R squared was 0.91

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten to understand the error of my ways. The MSE is 1/n (No of Samples) multiplied by the summation of the actual response subtracted by the predicted response SQUARED. Hence the error given will be SQUARED the expected error value. what I should have looked out for was the RMSE which will find the sqrt of the MSE. my predictions were off as well and that was because I scaled my values. Un-scaled X values gave me much better predictions. This I will have to look into more as I do not understand why.